# Pandas .sort_values does not sort as expected

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataframe created from a dict that I'm trying to sort by a certain row, but df.sort_values does not sort as I expect.

```
score_data = {'Name': ['Ben', 'Kyle', 'Joe'],
              'Team Name': ['team1', 'team1', 'team1'],
              'Score': [120, 50, 200]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(score_data)
df.sort_values('Name', ascending=True, inplace=True)
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Trying to sort by column 'Score', what I expect is:

```
Name Team Name  Score
 Joe     team1    200
 Ben     team1    120
Kyle     team1     50
```

But what I actually get is:

```
Name Team Name  Score
 Ben     team1    120
 Joe     team1    200
Kyle     team1     50
```

What am I missing here?

Edit: I passed the wrong column name to the sort_values function. Duh.

Comment: You want to sort by Score, not Name

Comment: @JackMoody I realized this as soon as I hit submit. I should have check my syntax first, duh. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are sorting my "Name" not by "Score".

```
df.sort_values('Name', ascending=True, inplace=True)
```

Change that to:

```
df.sort_values('Score', ascending=True, inplace=True)
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
    df.sort_values('Score', ascending=False, inplace=False)
```

`ascending = False` will sort values from High to Low for you.